# Medium script to embed not working

Tags: javascript, drupal, embed

I'm using Drupal to embed the widget Medium profile , but when loading the page the following errors appear in the console and the widget is not generated correctly.

```
embed-frame.bundle.NoHmxLqhwXL_4tl9CwlL2Q.js:630 Can not define setters/getters for "mi", property name already exists.

embed-frame.bundle.NoHmxLqhwXL_4tl9CwlL2Q.js:33697 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
```

The error occurs when trying to embed the widget to any profile Medium.

I think the error comes from Medium , but if anyone has found a solution I would appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: What is "widget Medium profile"? How are you embedding it?

Comment: leave a link for more information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_%28service%29 and embed the widget documentation here https://medium.com/@Medium/embed-medium-anywhere-3eaed64aed8a

Comment: How are you embedding it?

Comment: Show medium.com/@Medium/embed-medium-anywhere-3eaed64aed8a